# How to refer to the target in jQuery DOM manipulation?

Tags: jquery

I would like to add elements after the selected elements using jQuery, and say I would like to generate a new element with the same name as the target.

```
$("input:checkbox").after("<input type='hidden' name='...' value='...'/>");
```

I suppose I have to do this with string concatenation:

```
$("input:checkbox").after("<input type='hidden' name='"+ <how to refer here to the target?>+"' value='...'/>");
```

**Question**

How can I refer to the actual target in the parameter expression of `after()`? When using jQuery event listeners, I know I got the event, and its `target` property will be the DOM element, but here I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `each`, you get a callback, from which you can reference the element iterated over.

```
$("input:checkbox").each(function() {
  // `this` now refers to the input

  // maybe you want something like
  $(this).after("<input type='hidden' name='" + this.name + "' etc
});
```

```js
$("input:checkbox").each(function() {
  $(this).after("<input name='" + this.name + "'>");
});
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo">
```